# Cocoa-Touch - Loading a text file into an array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, debugging

Whats wrong with my code.. I want it to read a text file like

Item1

Item2

Item3

Item4

Item5

and parse it into an array so each line is a separate object in thus array.

When you check the console it prints `(null)`

```
-(void)parseIntoArray{ //parse the files into seprate arrays.
    allPools = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"ALL_POOLS_NAMES"];
    NSLog(@"%@",allPools);
}
```

I put the txt file in my project and copied it to destination.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly, can you verify that the file exists where you are looking and is readable?
Use

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] isReadableFileAtPath:aPath];
```

Secondly, what is in your file. The behaviour of **initWithContentsOfFile:**

> The array representation in the file identified by aPath **must contain only property list objects** (NSString, NSData, NSArray, or NSDictionary objects).

Is your file a valid plist xml file?

**InResponse**

You cannot use the NSArray constructor **initWithContentsOfFile:** to parse a regular text file.

Instead you can read the file content into memory and parse it yourself into an array. For your example you could use

```
//pull the content from the file into memory
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:aPath];
//convert the bytes from the file into a string
NSString* string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes]
                                            length:[data length] 
                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

//split the string around newline characters to create an array
NSString* delimiter = @"\n";
NSArray* items = [string componentsSeparatedByString:delimiter];
```

Comment: Hmm i got an error.. `encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];` it says its missing a `:` before the `]`

are you missing a argument?

Comment: @shorty876: No, he has one too many [ characters at the beginning.

Comment: oh wow i was trying to fix it myself but i was only looking at the closing brackets...
thanksss

Comment: @Jeremy: Opps, I was going to put an autorelease but forgot by the time I looked up the UTF8 constant! Thanks.

Comment: Print this is..... `"[",
    "  {",
    "    \"name\": \"Afghanistan\",",
    "    \"dial_code\": \"+93\",",
    "    \"code\": \"AF\"",
    "  },",`