# Quickest way to load word-list dictionary into an array?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory

I am working on a word-based game, and I need to load my 180,000 word dictionary (1.9MB) into an array so the solving algorithm can work with it. The dictionary is simply one word per line, like this:

```
a
ab
abs
absolutely
etc
...
```

Right now I am using the following code to load that file into the array:

```
NSString *txtPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dict" ofType:@"txt"];
        NSString *stringFromFile = [[NSString alloc]
                                    initWithContentsOfFile:txtPath
                                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                    error:&error ];       
for (NSString *word in [stringFromFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r\n"]) {
            [wordsArray addObject:word];
        }
```

This takes about 3-4 seconds on an iPhone 4. Probably even slower on older iOS devices. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: [Possibly you can try this link][1]

almost same question

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295527/cocoa-touch-loading-a-text-file-into-an-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this in the background, off the main thread using Grand Central Dispatch, or GCD.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0),^(void){
        NSString *txtPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dict" ofType:@"txt"];
        NSString *stringFromFile = [[NSString alloc]
                                    initWithContentsOfFile:txtPath
                                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                    error:&error ];       
        for (NSString *word in [stringFromFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r\n"]) {
            [wordsArray addObject:word];
        } 
});
```

I wrote the enclosing dispatch code from memory, but it's close (if not correct) and I think you get the idea.

**EDIT:** You can execute this code on the main thread, but what happens is a non-main-thread dispatch queue is where your code executes, thereby NOT blocking the UI.

You can improve the performance of your code here a little bit by replacing the `for` loop with just this:

```
[wordsArray setArray:[stringFromFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r\n"]];
```

There should be no need to iterate over the result from `-componentsSeparatedByString:` (an array) just to put them into *another* array. With 180K words, that should be a significant time saving right there.

Comment: I am going to do it off the main thread, but I still would like it to be faster as I dont want the user to wait that long if possible. Would doing some find/replaces on the dictionary and then declaring the array like `wordArray = [ "entry1", 
"entry2", 
"entry3" ]`
be faster or slower?

Comment: Thanks - the code improvement knocked it down to 2-3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be faster to pre-load the word list into an SQLite database, then use SQL queries to search using whatever patterns you have. You can take advantages of indexes to make it even faster.