# Is there an equivalent of Delphi TStringList in Cocoa/Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, delphi, tstringlist

I'm currently trying to learn Cocoa/Objective-C to build Mac OS X softwares. I come from Delphi, and in Delphi a really really useful element is the TStringList. I'm looking for an equivalent in Objective-C... I need to be able to access an item (one line) in the virtual list.

For example, in Delphi I can call `Label.Caption := MyStrList[5];` to display (as a String) an item in the list. I would like to do "the same" thing in Cocoa.

For info, I used TStringList in Delphi to manage the list of operations that my multi-threaded applications had to do.

Thanks in advance !

Beny

Comment: TStringList does *lots* of things. It splits and joins multiline blocks of text. It acts like an INI file. It acts like an associative array. It does file and stream I/O. It searches and sorts. It notifies you when it changes. It can have descendants. Also, it happens to store a list of strings. The body of your question seems to request something that merely stores a list of strings, which is nothing close to being an "equivalent" to TStringList. Please [edit] your question to clarify what you really want. (And TStringList isn't a "virtual" list; it really is a list.)

Comment: Hi Rob. Thanks for your comment. By virtual list I mean "not visual". I wanted to be on the right track and the reply from Aknew helped me. Now I'll experiment to replicate some basic StringList functions like Adding an item (...).

Comment: As a delphi guy learning objectiveC, I have wanted a "TStringList.LoadFromFile", for example, and found that a simple NSString where the whole string is loaded from a file, would be more common (followed perhaps by a second operation to split it up line by line). If I find I am repeatedly writing multiline or complex boilerplate code, I refactor that out into a utility "category" on NSArray or NSString.

Comment: Warren, thanks for your reply as Delphi user :) Excatly, I used NSString for "basic" string manipulation from file (read/write) ; and NSArray for using a string list as items. In my opinion, the logic of Objective-C is not so easy (from a Delphi view). I mean that in Delphi a function is called `function`, a procedure `procedure`, code begins by `begin`and finish by `end`, ... The transition to Objective-C is not easy (in my cas anyway) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its NSArray (or NSMutableArray) with NSString objects in it. You can  write something like

```
NSArray *array=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"string1",@"string2",@"string3",nil];
label.text=[array objectAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: Ah, ok ! I thought to it but this solution seemed to be a patch-up job... So we have to do manually what Delphi does "in one line". Now I understand that my question can be a duplicate of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295527/cocoa-touch-loading-a-text-file-into-an-array. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: *So we have to do manually what Delphi does "in one line"*  I don't undestand you, what Delphi do in one line? Load from the file?

Comment: By the way, it need not load file to NSData and than convert it to NSString like in reference, NSString can load file themself with `+ (id)stringWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error` .

Comment: Ok, thanks for your inputs. About the "in one line", I mean that we have to mix NSArray and NSString. There is not a native virtual list ready. I'll make some tests right now. Thanks again :)

Comment: Perfect ! Here is the code I just used for a simple test : http://pastebin.com/nradADdX